# How can i extract the image out of 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to file via windbg?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, windbg

I have a memory dump file with what seems to be a memory leak of 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' objects.
I have multiple objects of that type and !gcroot doesn't help me to identify where the leak is.

example output:

> DOMAIN(0071D148):HANDLE(Pinned):1513e8:Root: 
>   03335250(System.Object[])->   0248e8ec(System.Drawing.Bitmap)

I had an idea to extract the image from the memory dump into an image file and then, when i can see what is the image that's leaking, i could examine the source code surround the creation of that specific bitmap.

So, how is it possible to write the memory into a file which i could open in an image viewer and see the image that Bitmap object hold?

Also, if you have other ideas how to identify the leak source i'd be happy to hear them.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System.Drawing.Bitmap is a tiny managed object.  It wraps a handle returned by the unmanaged GDI+ api, stored in the private *nativeImage* field.  Finding the bitmap data from that handle is an exercise in needle in the haystack hunting.  Nor is that bitmap data in any way compatible with an image file format, only the Bitmap::Save() call can do that, running the required image encoder.

Scratch this idea.

Having memory problems with Bitmap objects is otherwise *very* common.  Far too many programmers ignore that Bitmap inherits IDisposable.  You can write a lot of .NET programs and never once call Dispose() or use the *using* statement and the program runs just fine.  The garbage collector keeps them out of trouble.  The Bitmap class however is the singular .NET class where that cannot work anymore.  The problem is that it is **tiny**.  You can create tens of thousands of them before ever triggering a garbage collection.  Not nearly often enough to get the garbage collector to release the unmanaged GDI+ handle.  As a result, the program runs *very* heavy, using lots of unmanaged memory.  An OOM crash is very likely when the program runs in 32-bit mode.  Or a commit size of gigabytes in 64-bit mode

Before getting lost in Windbg, first carefully review the source code for the program.  And verify that you can pair *every* Bitmap variable with a corresponding Dispose() call or *using* statement.  Watch out of things like assigning a PictureBox.Image property without code that calls the Dispose() method on the previous image.  A .NET memory profiler is otherwise the better tool to debug this.

Comment: thanks for your comment. i'm dealing with a very large program and it is very hard to scan all the places where Bitmaps are in use. that is why i though my idea could direct me to a more specific place in the code.

Comment: It is not a comment, it is an answer.  With the last sentence leaving little doubt how you need to tackle this problem in a very large program.  Memory profilers show the needles in the haystack, that's their job.

Comment: the memory dump is from a customer and the problem doesn't duplicate in my environment so i can't debug it in real-time with profiler. anyway thanks again for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It seems still possible to [dump all bitmaps from memory](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cd86ddf7-da4b-4b85-a737-b516dbb13d03/windows-form-application-use-a-huge-amount-of-memory-in-vista-but-not-in-xp?forum=winforms), if you really want to do it.

The steps:

1. `!dumpheap -short -type System.Drawing.Bitmap`
2. `!do <address>`
3. Find offset of property `nativeImage`
4. `dps` on that IntPtr (equal to `dps poi(<address>+<offset>)` ?) gives you the type
5. `dt <address> <type>` --> InternalBitmap property
6. `dt <internalAddress> <internalType>` --> Bmp property
7. `dt <bmpAddress> <bmpType>` gives Scan0 property, which is the start address

I just couldn't follow on how to calculate the size of the bitmap, which would be needed to do a `.writemem`. There is width and height and probably PixelFormat could be used to calculate the bits per pixel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Thomas's reference [dump all bitmaps from memory](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/cd86ddf7-da4b-4b85-a737-b516dbb13d03/windows-form-application-use-a-huge-amount-of-memory-in-vista-but-not-in-xp?forum=winforms), I've found a way to save bitmap to a file.

When I followed the steps in the post, I've met a problem in step 5, **Symbol GdiPlus!GpBitmap not found.**

```
0:000> !do 00000234`ba162b80
Name:        System.Drawing.Bitmap
MethodTable: 00007ffb854ebed8
EEClass:     00007ffb854f2fd0
Size:        48(0x30) bytes
File:        C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
00007ffbb2545dd8  40005ba        8        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 __identity
00007ffbb25c31f8  400018e       20        System.IntPtr  1 instance      234fcaccb60 nativeImage
00007ffbb254aaa0  400018f       10        System.Byte[]  0 instance 0000000000000000 rawData
00007ffbb2545dd8  4000190       18        System.Object  0 instance 00000234ba28e908 userData
00007ffb854eac20  400009c       58 System.Drawing.Color  1   static 0000000000000000 defaultTransparentColor

0:000> dps 234fcaccb60
00000234`fcaccb60  00007ffb`ca656618 GdiPlus!GpBitmap::`vftable'
00000234`fcaccb68  00000000`676d4931
00000234`fcaccb70  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccb78  ffffffff`00000001
00000234`fcaccb80  00000234`91eaf0a0
00000234`fcaccb88  00000000`00000001
00000234`fcaccb90  00007ffb`ca656588 GdiPlus!EpScanBitmap::`vftable'
00000234`fcaccb98  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccba0  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccba8  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccbb0  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccbb8  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccbc0  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccbc8  00000006`00000000
00000234`fcaccbd0  00000000`00000001
00000234`fcaccbd8  00000234`fcc9e850
0:000> dt 234fcaccb60 GdiPlus!GpBitmap
Symbol GdiPlus!GpBitmap not found.
```

I've found several posts in stackoverflow which have the same problem. But there're no answeres how to fix the problem.

The key point to save image data is to find out the raw data address, which is Scan0 of the Bitmap.

From the post, we can know the route is as follows: Bitmap object address -> nativeImage object address -> CopyOnWriteBitmap object address -> GpMemoryBitmapobject object address -> Scan0 address.

Although I have error on command: dt 234fcaccb60 GdiPlus!GpBitmap, I can still find out the CopyOnWriteBitmap object address. And find out GpMemoryBitmapobject address according to CopyOnWriteBitmap object address. And   finally find out the Scan0 address. Because the memory layout is fixed. Using **dt** command, we can easily see the CopyOnWriteBitmap object address and GpMemoryBitmapobject address. But without **dt** command, we can still see the address position according the post.

```
0:000> !do 00000234`ba162b80
Name:        System.Drawing.Bitmap
MethodTable: 00007ffb854ebed8
EEClass:     00007ffb854f2fd0
Size:        48(0x30) bytes
File:        C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
00007ffbb2545dd8  40005ba        8        System.Object  0 instance 0000000000000000 __identity
00007ffbb25c31f8  400018e       20        System.IntPtr  1 instance      234fcaccb60 nativeImage
00007ffbb254aaa0  400018f       10        System.Byte[]  0 instance 0000000000000000 rawData
00007ffbb2545dd8  4000190       18        System.Object  0 instance 00000234ba28e908 userData
00007ffb854eac20  400009c       58 System.Drawing.Color  1   static 0000000000000000 defaultTransparentColor

0:000> dps 234fcaccb60
00000234`fcaccb60  00007ffb`ca656618 GdiPlus!GpBitmap::`vftable'
00000234`fcaccb68  00000000`676d4931
00000234`fcaccb70  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccb78  ffffffff`00000001
00000234`fcaccb80  00000234`91eaf0a0 ====================>CopyOnWriteBitmap
00000234`fcaccb88  00000000`00000001
00000234`fcaccb90  00007ffb`ca656588 GdiPlus!EpScanBitmap::`vftable'
00000234`fcaccb98  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccba0  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccba8  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccbb0  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccbb8  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccbc0  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcaccbc8  00000006`00000000
00000234`fcaccbd0  00000000`00000001
00000234`fcaccbd8  00000234`fcc9e850

0:000> dps 00000234`91eaf0a0
00000234`91eaf0a0  00007ffb`ca6567a8 GdiPlus!CopyOnWriteBitmap::`vftable'
00000234`91eaf0a8  0069006b`00000001
00000234`91eaf0b0  ffffffff`ffffffff
00000234`91eaf0b8  00000000`ffffffff
00000234`91eaf0c0  00000000`00000000
00000234`91eaf0c8  00000000`00000000
00000234`91eaf0d0  00000000`020007d0 dog_windows_x64_3146946!Ordinal9+0x7d0
00000234`91eaf0d8  00000001`00000004
00000234`91eaf0e0  00000000`00000000
00000234`91eaf0e8  00000000`00000000
00000234`91eaf0f0  00000000`00000000
00000234`91eaf0f8  00000234`fcc50a10 ====================>GpMemoryBitmap
00000234`91eaf100  00790073`00000000
00000234`91eaf108  00000000`00000000
00000234`91eaf110  00000000`00000000
00000234`91eaf118  00000000`00000000

0:000> dps 00000234`fcc50a10
00000234`fcc50a10  00007ffb`ca6568a8 GdiPlus!GpMemoryBitmap::`vftable'
00000234`fcc50a18  00007ffb`ca656860 GdiPlus!GpMemoryBitmap::`vftable'
00000234`fcc50a20  00007ffb`ca6567f0 GdiPlus!GpMemoryBitmap::`vftable'
00000234`fcc50a28  00007ffb`ca6567c0 GdiPlus!GpMemoryBitmap::`vftable'
00000234`fcc50a30  00000bb8`00001000 ====================>Height，Width
00000234`fcc50a38  00030803`00001000 ====================>PixelFormat, Stride
00000234`fcc50a40  00000234`98c30000 ====================>Scan0
00000234`fcc50a48  00000000`00020000
00000234`fcc50a50  ffffffff`00000001
00000234`fcc50a58  00400000`ffffffff
00000234`fcc50a60  40580000`00000000
00000234`fcc50a68  40580000`00000000
00000234`fcc50a70  00000000`00000001
00000234`fcc50a78  00000234`dd0dbe00
00000234`fcc50a80  00000000`00000000
00000234`fcc50a88  00000bb8`00001000

0:000> !address 00000234`98c30000

Usage:                  <unknown>
Base Address:           00000234`98c30000
End Address:            00000234`997e8000
Region Size:            00000000`00bb8000 (  11.719 MB)
State:                  00001000          MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000004          PAGE_READWRITE
Type:                   00020000          MEM_PRIVATE
Allocation Base:        00000234`98c30000
Allocation Protect:     00000004          PAGE_READWRITE


Content source: 1 (target), length: bb8000

0:000> .writemem D:\image.raw 00000234`98c30000 L0xbb8000
```

After saving image data to image.raw, we can use Photoshop to open it (input width, height which we get from the last **dps** command) and save it as bmp/png/jpg.